# Redirect to an url but showing a different url in the bar adress using tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servlets, http-redirect

When the website is full, I redirect the users to a try_later_page.html, and told them to try after a few moment,
But I want in that instant, that the adresse bar to contain mysite.com, and not the url mysite.com/try_later_page.html, so when the user try an F5 he will be send to the index page,

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a `forward`instead of a `redirect`. The forward is server intern and reroutes to the new content. The browser doesn't know anything about this rerouting and stays on the former url. So when the user use `F5` within the browser, the former site we be called once more (not the target site of the `forward`).

Comment: where do I have to use it, 
In my Java code, for now I have `((HttpServletResponse) response).sendRedirect(REDIRECT_PAGE)`,  what is the equivalent of forward ?

Comment: `request.getRequestDispatcher("URL").forward(request, response);`